# 1 hot encoding training and test data separately in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I need to add about `100` extra columns to `data.frame` based on the length of a previous `data.frame`

For example, I have two `data.frame`s `Xtrain` and `Xtest`. `Xtrain` as 1000 columns, but `Xtest` has only 900 columns. This difference is due to 1-hot encoding the `Xtrain` and `Xtest` separately.

How can I add those 100 missing columns (with all 0s) to `Xtest`? Also, the order of columns in the augmented `Xtest` should be same as `Xtrain`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
extra = setdiff(names(Xtrain), names(Xtest))

for (e in extra){
    Xtest$e <- 0
}
```

But this adds a column `e` not the corresponding entry in `extra`.

Comment: try `Xtest[,901:1000] <- 0`

Comment: try `Xtest[,extra] <- 0`